# File download link causing screen flash

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc

I have an anchor tag such as below:

```
<a href="/resource/download/3" target="_blank">MyResource.txt</a>
```

This calls an MVC controller to return a file:

```
    public FileResult Download(int id)
    {
        var resource = _context.Find<Resource>(id);
        var filePath = Path.Combine(Request.MapPath("~"), resource.FilePath);

        var fileBytes = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(filePath);
        return File(fileBytes, System.Net.Mime.MediaTypeNames.Application.Octet, resource.FileName);
    }
```

This all works great.  The issue I have is that the screen flashes to a blank tab very briefly before downloading the file.  I'm sure this is due to the target="_blank" attribute.  However if I remove that attribute than my main page URL changes to /resource/download/3.  This is not what I want.  How do I get the file download behavior without the screen tab/flash, or is it possible?

Comment: Are you using any JavaScript? jQuery maybe?

Answer (score -1):

Try to set the `Content-Disposition` and `Content-Type` HTTP headers for the response, i.e. set

```
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=MyResource.txt
Content-Type: application/octet-stream
```

for the response of your `.txt` file. Now your file should be downloaded even after removing `target="_blank"`.